# Elasticsearch - Custom stem override with wildcard character

Tags: elasticsearch, stemming

I have implemented light English stemming in Elasticsearch.

I'm able to add a custom stem override so that "Guitarist" => "Guitar", for example, but  I would like to add this as a general rule, so that "Guitarist" => "Guitar", "Violinist => Violin" etc.

Can I achieve this without using regex?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at a similar problem, it appears that regex is the only solution. Example below specifically for words ending "ist".

```
{
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "char_filter": [
                    "ist_filter"
                ],
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "my_stem"
                ]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "my_stem": {
                "type": "stemmer",
                "language": "light_english"
            }
        },
        "char_filter": {
            "ist_filter": {
                "type": "pattern_replace",
                "pattern": "(.*)ist$",
                "replacement": "$1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Exclusions can be added to the pattern e.g. the below would ignore the words "mist" and "twist", but this would only be practical for a (very) limited number of exclusions.

```
"pattern": "^(?!m|tw)(.*)ist$"
```